# How damaging would the loss of hearing, smell and sense of touch be on an open battlefield?

Tags: magic, military

[image]

Only hearing, smell and sense of touch would be affected, visibility/eye-sight would be unchanged. (effects are temporary)

Melee weapons : spears/polearms, swords, something something magic melee weapons....

Projectile weapons : bow & arrows, catapult, wood cannon (mostly useless), something something magic projectiles...

Battle tactics : line formations, classic cavalry-infantry-artillery divide....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107021/discussion-on-question-by-anonymousworldbuilding-how-damaging-would-the-loss-of).

Answer (score 33):

**Lethal**

Smell isn't the most important, but touch and hearing are. Touch represents all the tactile sensations in battle - i.e. your grip on your sword, for instance. Admittedly not much of a problem on a modern battlefield, given that you don't do a lot of clashing hand-to-hand, but on the ancient battlefield, this makes you sloppy, and sloppiness gets you killed.

Not like it makes much of a difference because lack of hearing will get you anyway. Eyes can only alert you to what's in front of you. That other basically 270 degrees of vision? It's the ears. Not to mention that ears are good for the relay of information, and if you can't respond to orders, you can't survive. I suppose you might be able to use vibration-based morse code to give orders - except since touch is out, you can't do that either! The only way to communicate would be by sight, which has it's drawbacks, mostly because if you're looking for someone trying to talk to you, you're ignoring all the people trying to stab/shoot you.

Long story short, touch and especially hearing are really important for humans and sensory deprivation is a death sentence, especially against opponents who aren't sensory deprived.

Comment: As pointed out by Li jun, I accidentally wrote "sight" in my original title when I actually meant only hearing, smell and touch would be affected.  Sight and taste (arguably useless) would be left intact.

Comment: Touch is far more important. Without it, you would have little sense of proprioception, you'd fumble with familiar objects, you'd not be able to walk, let alone navigate a battle field (look into diabetic neuropathy); you'd not be able to sense changes in terrain and will most likely suffer injuries before you ever got out of your own camp.

Comment: I would argue that touch would be a far greater problem in modern battlefields as there is a much greater emphasis on fine motor movements. Think of the small movements a soldier would have to do to reload a rifle, for example- undoing a magazine pouch, hitting the magazine release catch,  loading a new magazine and clambering a new round. Swinging a sword, raising a shield are all gross motor movements that wouldn't probably be as impacted by loss of touch

Comment: Riflery will be made difficult without touch: Trigger control is a key component of accurate rifle fire (the others being position, sight picture, and breathing), and it needs touch.

Comment: Due to touch being affected, how would the loss of hearing still be relevant? Even if they were busy in a melee (especially in a melee) they would lose grip of their weapons as they dont know how much pressure they exert on the hilt and likely fall over. That wouldnt be very lethal with a unlucky accident the biggest risk.

Comment: Only a few soldiers are affected, or everyone? If not everyone, then it's not that big of a problem. Soldiers fought in close formations, so there is no need to hear what's behind you. Just follow what the others are doing, and hold up your formation in the shield wall, while stabbing forward with your spear, and maneuver where all the others around you are maneuvering.

Comment: I often read/heard that the noise during a battle is a bit deafening. I wonder if loosing hearing wouldn't actually be a benefit that allows someone to focus a bit better.

Comment: @Jack you sound like someone who never tried to fence. And who never got his hand numb when doing it. It is simply impossible to use a sword if you don't feel what you are doing. You'll drop it at first hit, or you'll quench your fist as hard as you can the whole time and get tired and drop it few minutes later. I'm in no way sword fighting expert, but numb hands are not uncommon for beginners so I know a bit firsthand. I'm not saying anything you wrote about modern warfare is false, I'm just not sure is it really worse than being dead in five.

Comment: @Mołot I once sat leaning in such a fashion that made my arm go numb. I lost Proprioception in that arm and when I went to bring it in front of my face to see why it felt weird I smacked myself in the face. Hard.

Comment: The weapons described make this sound like a late medieval battlefield.  In that case, the typical infantry formation will be a shield wall, pike square, or other rigid formation, and hearing (and what's going on behind you) won't be that important unless the formation disintigrates.

Comment: @Mark Hearing would be *critically* important, because how else will you receive the orders that keep that formation rigid through maneuvers? Don't forget, you've also lost touch so you won't notice the people next to you shifting stance until they either knock you over or move into your field of vision...

Comment: @Jack Even if they retained their proprioception, they still couldn't even walk.  Proprioception tells you were your hands and feet are, but it doesn't tell you where the ground is or when you foot is actually on the ground.  You foot's sense of touch does that.  Without it you *CAN NOT Walk*, except by continuously staring down at your feet.  And then of course you wouldn't know when or if your sword arm had actually hit someone with your sword.

Comment: Oops, sorry Jack, that was for @elemtilas.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Yep. We're on the same here I think!

Answer (score 11):

**One from column A one from column B:**

I think both Demigan and Halfthawed each have half the correct answer. The fuller picture I think largely comes down to timing.

1. If the alt-chemical agent takes effect *during an active phase of battle*, while soldiers are actually fighting, then I think **FATAL** is the right answer. Loss of hearing & smell won't affect much, except that soldiers can't hear the bugle calls. The loss of touch will be far more important. Without it, you would have little sense of proprioception, because you can't physically feel where you are and can only orient by sight. You'd fumble with familiar objects, like sword or mace or bow and not be able to wield them effectively. You'd be as likely to be hit by a fellow soldier as by an enemy and would also be at risk from slashing or bashing yourself. You'd not be able to walk, let alone navigate a battle field (look into diabetic neuropathy) and would not be able sense changes in terrain (dead bodies, broken bits of weapons & fortification works) and will most likely stumble and fall and break an ankle or suffer some other debilitating injuries within a few minutes. The melee would become a crawl fest of soldiers lying down or creeping about trying to kill each other. Until they finally give up the cause as even more vain & stupid than a regular battle.
2. If the alt-chemical agent takes effect when soldiers are *in camp or arrayed before battle*, then I think **STOP THE FIGHTING BEFORE IT EVER STARTS** is the right answer. Whoever is down wind of the agent will simply not be able to engage in the fight and if they try, will not be able to put up any kind of effective defense, because of the agent's effects. They won't be able to properly equip themselves or move into their positions because they can't feel anything.

   If the wind remains constant, then the aggressor might be able to safely cross the lines and all but slaughter the affected foe. Breezes often shift, however, and it's more than likely that the aggressor will get a taste of its own weapon. Neither side will be able to field an effective army and it won't take long for even the most pigheaded of field marshals to realise that use of this weapon is dangerous for both sides and a monumental waste of effort.

These general effects are timeless. It doesn't matter much if you're trying to strap on greaves and a helmet or knocking an arrow to bowstring or if you're trying to drive a tank or enter commands into a guidance computer. The loss of the sense of touch will make you a very ineffective soldier.

Comment: +1 but worth mentioning that archers would be more affected than melee fighters who can see who is in front of them and the weapon they are holding.  Archers can either look at their target or they can look at a gesticulating figure who is trying to indicate who they should shoot at, but not both, and they need touch to determine if they have drawn to the correct anchor point as they can't see it without a mirror.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Not so much on the latter. Proprioception tells you where your draw is up to, even if you can't feel your fingers. This is not the same thing as "touch".

Comment: Seconds after the chemical is used everyone would stop fighting because they are unable to continue. The correct answer would be "bruised with a handful of more serious injuries". Why would they still crawl at each other after something this debilitating?

Comment: @Demigan - Becoz ooman brain slo an dumm. I didn't say they'd be crawling around hacking at each other for hours! But there is likely to be some undefinable moments of time where butchery will continue even after the agent takes effect. There are (apparently) no respiratory effects, so there won't be any dramatic gasping and hacking and flailing as the lungs & mucus membranes are attacked. There will be very little stimulus for the conscious brain to work on for several seconds to a minute anyway.

Comment: yeah i believe both army will just hide behind their shield wall till their sense return in both scenario and strap shield is a must, if this happen to cavalry they are screwed even without charging, assuming horse also affected by propioception and have same effect despite quadruped. but iam curious with this loss of sense, they still can sleep right ? even when under propioception?

Comment: @LiJun - I believe they'd be able to sleep normally. If the agent hits you whilst you're asleep, you may just wake up refreshed and ready for a new day's warmongering, never even being aware that you'd temporarily lost 3 of your 20 or so senses.

Comment: i mean when they get hit by this and then they decide to goes to sleep.

Answer (score 8):

It would likely stop the fighting for the most part.

1: communication stops. Only visual communication would still work which is great for large-scale combat but for the small-scale "there's something over there is it friendly or not?" Communication its a lot less useful until we have augmented reality like technology.

2: smell is heavily tied to memory, but I don't think it'll be a big loss.

3: touch is rather important. Even if other senses like proprioception aren't affected touch is incredibly important. (proprioception: he ability to know where your limbs are in relation to your body, touch your nose with your eyes closed). In trials where people's sense of touch was deactivated and they were tasked to grab something while not being able to see it they were unable to do so. With touch activated your hand will feel the object and be able to let the rest of the hand close around it without moving it. Without touch you push the object and don't know when you have to close your hand around it.

This causes problems in many area's. If you walk across ground you dont feel how much pressure you put on it, how slippery it is. If you lift a weapon you have to look at it in order to get your hand on the trigger (or a button, a steering wheel, control stick etc) and grab it correctly, but since you don't feel it you don't know when you squeeze or push it, how much pressure you put into it when steering a vehicle or craft. You don't know when you will fire your weapon(s), you don't know when you'll move across something that makes you slip and fall. I don't think that people will be able to fight in those conditions especially if they are deaf as well.

Comment: Great ! Exactly what I'm looking, it will my world's analogue to chemical warfare. The effects will be short lived. Thank you

Comment: Accidentally wrote "sight" in my original title when I actually meant only hearing, smell and touch would be affected.

Comment: I noticed but your question with the pictures was clear enough.

Comment: I strongly suspect that proprioception *would* be affected - consider the likelihood of biting your tongue or cheek while eating due to the local anaesthetic following a filling at the dentist.  Everything is still able to move perfectly well, you just aren't getting any feedback...

Answer (score 6):

If this was to become common, it would likely affect the way units are formed and move tactically.

The classical Phalanx essentially packed all the troops into a sardine can like formation where not only were you protected by the shield of the man beside you, but the impetus of the file of men behind you actually was used to drive you forward into the enemy. Soldiers also had some protection from the spear points of the men behind them over their shoulders and providing a bristling "hedge" of spearpoints. The men in the middle of the Phalanx effectively were blind and deaf during most of the battle (their sight was limited by the helmet, the bodies of the men around them and clouds of dust raised by the struggling men, while their hearing was also limited by the helmets and the clash of bronze on bronze and wood, or the screams of the wounded and dying. A unit trained in this mode of fighting likely isn't going to be negatively effected by a spell or chemical agent acting in the way the OP describes once in formation and on the move.

[image]

*Classical Phalanx*

Since I am unclear of the effectiveness of this spell/chemical, it is also possible that fast moving and dispersed units like horse archers might also remain effective. Their ability to see and engage targets by archery isn't likely to be affected, although how well they can control their horses might be an issue. Even so, they could simply come to a halt and shower the enemy with arrows while slowly retreating until the effects pass. Samurai (at least early ones) were also trained as horse archers (Bushido can be roughly translated as "the way of horse and bow"), so would have similar tactical responses. The main difference is a Samurai will spend the extra time while stopped to aim and hit his specific marked target rather than count on something like an arrow storm.

[image]

*We can still see you as well*

[image]

*He can see you as well*

Comment: Yeah, I think a disciplined army like a Roman legion could still be somewhat effective. It doesn't take much individual skill. Just protect yourself and the men beside you with your shield and stab indiscriminatly forward through the gaps. Loss of touch could still be a problem, but I feel like you would still notice if someone is pressing on your shield. The would definitly be weekened, but if they were prepared for it, I think they could put up a fight.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think you're confusing hearing loss due to ambient sound being too loud to hear anything properly with hearing loss due to nerve damage. In any event, the crackest most disciplines most well trained veterans of ancient phalanx soldiers will still fumble and stumble and injure themselves and possibly kill one another once the sense of touch sets in. Just imagine your entire body, from scalp to toes, has "fallen asleep", is entirely numb. You have no idea if you're still even holding your spear or shield; You can't feel the ground or your shoes. You just end up in a heap!

Answer (score 3):

It might be highly effective against cavalry. Not much effect on humans, unless you knocked out things like sense of balance along with hearing and proprioception along with touch, but horses would likely be totally spooked and panic -- unless, like horses trained to tolerate gunfire, they had previously bene exposed and habituated.

Answer (score 3):

The sense of touch may be important for another reason.  The sense of pain.  This is actually carried by a completely separate set of nerves, and can be lost independently of the rest of touch, but....

Without a sense of pain, warriors would not know they had been hit unless they saw the injury.  They might well keep right on fighting until they died.  (Though proprioception might let them know they are not moving correctly.)

Comment: This was my first thought, too. An army that feels no pain will be hard to stop, although they'll be clumsy without proprioception.

Comment: @NuclearWang hard to stop short term, but their attrition could be terrible if every injured soldier dies.

Comment: @DavidG. I don't think there is any sense of pain in battle (at least not in the same way imagine it is)... Adrenaline will get you moving till you can't anymore. And then without antibiotics you die. Terrible losses caused by battlefield injures usually have not stopped military conflicts (dirty water on other hand)... and now with clean water and antibiotics...